# Merging two columns which don't overlap and create new columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([["2014", "q2"]],
                   columns=('Year', 'Quarter'))

df2 = pd.DataFrame([["2016", "q1"], 
                    ["2015", "q1"]],
                   columns=('Year', 'Quarter'))


print(df1.merge(df2, on='Year', how='outer'))
```

Results in:

```
   Year   Quarter_x    Quarter_y
0   2016    NaN         q1
1   2015    NaN         q1
2   2014    q2          NaN
```

What I would like to get is:

```
   Year     Quarter
0  2016      q1
1  2015      q1
2  2014      q2
```

Is there a simple way to do this with the merge() or some other function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df1.merge(df2, on=['Year', 'Quarter'], how='outer').dropna()
```

to get:

```
   Year Quarter
0  2014      q2
1  2016      q1
2  2015      q1
```

You can also look into pd.concat().

Comment: The strings were not intentional, so I placed None into each slot to represent a NaN.

Comment: See updated. Depending on what your data look like, you can also add `.drop_duplicates()`.

Comment: Sorry about the mixup. The above now represents the problem. If you can edit your response, then thanks, otherwise I can repost it for you...

Comment: See the follow up to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801230/merging-two-or-more-columns-which-dont-overlap