# Merging two or more columns which don't overlap

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Follow up to this post:
[Merging two columns which don't overlap and create new columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800486/merging-two-columns-which-dont-overlap-and-create-new-columns/37800550?noredirect=1#comment63066935_37800550)

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([["2014", "q2", 2],
                   ["2013", "q1", 1],],
                   columns=('Year', 'Quarter', 'Value'))

df2 = pd.DataFrame([["2016", "q1", 3], 
                    ["2015", "q1", 3]],
                   columns=('Year', 'Quarter', 'Value'))


print(df1.merge(df2, on='Year', how='outer'))
```

Results in:

```
  Year   Quarter_x  Value_x  Quarter_y  Value_y
0  2014        q2        2       NaN     NaN
1  2013        q1        1       NaN     NaN
2  2016       NaN      NaN        q1     3
3  2015       NaN      NaN        q1     3
```

But I want to get this:

```
   Year    Quarter   Value 
0  2014        q2        2      
1  2013        q1        1     
2  2016        q1        3
3  2015        q1        3
```

Note: This doesn't produce the desired result... :(

```
print(df1.merge(df2, on=['Year', 'Quarter','Value'], how='outer').dropna())

   Year Quarter  Value
0  2014      q2      2
1  2013      q1      1
```

... using 'left' or right' or inner also don't cut it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what's happening here, but if I do

```
df1.merge(df2, on=['Year', 'Quarter', 'Value'], how='outer').dropna()
```

I get:

```
   Year Quarter  Value
0  2014      q2    2.0
1  2013      q1    1.0
2  2016      q1    3.0
3  2015      q1    3.0
```

You may want to take a look at the [merge, join & concat docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html).

The most 'intuitive' way for this is probably [`.append()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

```
df1.append(df2)

   Year Quarter  Value
0  2014      q2    2.0
1  2013      q1    1.0
2  2016      q1    3.0
3  2015      q1    3.0
```

If you look into the source code, you'll find it calls `concat` behind the scenes.

`Merge` is useful and intended for cases where you have `columns` with overlapping values.

Answer (score 2):

pandas `concat` is much better suited for this.

```
pd.concat([df1, df2]).reset_index(drop=True)

   Year Quarter  Value
0  2014      q2      2
1  2013      q1      1
2  2016      q1      3
3  2015      q1      3
```

`concat` is intended to place one dataframe adjacent to another while keeping the index or columns aligned.  In the default case, it keeps the columns aligned.  Considering your example dataframes, the columns are aligned and your stated expected output shows `df2` placed exactly after `df1` where the columns are aligned.  Every aspect of what you've asked for is exactly what `concat` was designed to provide.  All I've done is point you to an appropriate function.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the append feature:

```
df_final = df1.append(df2)
```